Should I use CD74HCT4067 as 16:1 analog multiplexer or design my own multiplexer using Mosfets?
I was thinking to design an 16:1 analog multiplexer using transmission gate and and gate based decoder circuit. But I was advised to use CD74HCT4067 instead as our design is an off-chip design. I am confused when to use this IC and when to design our own multiplexer? Also, what does actually mean by on-chip and off-chip multiplexer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

One thing they fail to teach you in school is that it’s near impossible to make transmission gates with discrete MOSFETs. You need the body connections of the PMOS/NMOS to be tied to VDD/VSS, but discrete MOSFETs can’t do this. There are some exceptions, like MOSFET ICs from Advanced Linear Devices and also one of the CMOS pairs in the CD4007. You can also make analog switches using back-to-back N-channel discrete MOSFETs and also switches using JFETs, but these have their limitations and I also wouldn’t call them transmission gates.

If some single-chip product will satisfy your requirements and you are satisfied with availability and such like, then you can just compare cost (up-front engineering costs, and per-unit costs including PCB area and testing).
This is very situational, so it's something you will have to do for yourself.
Parts like the 74HC4067/74HCT4067/CD4067B/74HC4066 etc. do not have internal level translation on the control inputs so you would need to provide that if the system needs bipolar supplies. You also have to pay attention to the maximum voltage ratings- some parts such as 74HC4066 will work . They are analog switch parts made with a digital process and are generally not specified as tightly as analog switch parts such as DG406 which has guaranteed resistance flatness and guaranteed charge injection. Some have extra circuitry to provide protection against overvoltage that you might otherwise have to add externally. Of course that performance comes at a price.
There are hundreds (at least) of different analog switch and multiplexer parts so it may take some effort to decide. Start by listing your requirements for voltage range, 'on' resistance, resistance flatness with changing input voltage, charge injection, control voltage range, and non-technical things like cost and availability.
If you're making a one-off in a first-world country you could certainly choose to use one of the better muxes on the market regardless of cost or future availability because the overall cost won't change much. If you're making a high volume consumer product the choice would be quite different. If you are designing an industrial or commercial product that has a long life cycle, the decisions might be different again.
